# Dagger2 Binding issue

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have two modules one for ViewModelModule Providers and another for Application level which contains retrofit,intent. So before passing to the component I have included the ViewModelModule to the ApplicationModule like this

```
@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class ApplicationModule {
```

And My component interface is Like:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ApplicationModule::class, ContextModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(activity: LoginActivity)
    fun inject(activity: RegisterActivity)
    fun inject(activity: SplashActivity)

}
```

ApplicationModule class

```
@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
class ApplicationModule {

    @Singleton
    @Named("GotoLogin")
    @Provides
    fun provideSplashIntent(appCompatActivity: AppCompatActivity): Intent {
        return Intent(appCompatActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Named("GotoDashboard")
    @Provides
    fun provideLoginIntent(appCompatActivity: AppCompatActivity): Intent {
        return Intent(appCompatActivity, DashboardActivity::class.java)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Named("GotoRegister")
    @Provides
    fun provideRegisterIntent(appCompatActivity: AppCompatActivity): Intent {
        return Intent(appCompatActivity, RegisterActivity::class.java)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideTimer(): Timer {
        return Timer()
    }
}
```

ViewModelModule class

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindviewmodelFactory(factory: DaggerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(LoginViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindLoginViewModel(loginViewModel: LoginViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(RegisterViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindRegisterViewModel(registerViewModel: RegisterViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

Scenario:
Suppose when I trying to use a function from ApplicationModule Class in LoginActivity then the Error is coming.

Usage:

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel
    lateinit var context: Context
    @Named("GotoRegister")
    @Inject
    lateinit var regiseterIntent: Intent
```

But when I am trying to use anything from the ApplicationModule class a compile error is coming

```
Crony\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\app\crony\di\AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
    public abstract interface AppComponent {
                    ^
          androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity is injected at
              com.app.crony.di.ApplicationModule.provideRegisterIntent(appCompatActivity)
          @javax.inject.Named("GotoRegister") android.content.Intent is injected at
              com.app.crony.LoginActivity.regiseterIntent
```

Full Source Code:
[Github Link](https://github.com/avik1990/Crony)

I can feel that I am missing something but not able to sort out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `activity` with `context`. It will work well.

Comment: where exactly I will replace?

Comment: `AppCompatActivity` replace by `Context` when provide `Intent`.